# Method invocation failed because system.string doesn't contain a method named 'WaitForStatus''

Tags: powershell

I am trying to stops some services with a PS script , but the I think the type is incorrect. When the script iterates through the array it returns "method invocation failed because system.string doesn't contain a method named 'WaitForStatus'". I need be sure the services have stopped before running the next script.

```
Foreach ($i in $services){
    (get-service  -ComputerName Server1 | Where {$_.name -eq "$i"}).stop()
    $i.WaitForStatus('Stopped')
}

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: How is `$services` assigned? It needs to be something similar to `$services = Get-Service ....`.

Comment: as `AdminOfThings` pointed out, you are running `.WaitForStatus('Stopped')` on a _string_ since that is what is in your `$Services` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't make it clear where/how `$services` is defined, it seems that it is simply a list of service names (i.e. `system.string` as the error states).  To use the `WaitForStatus()` method, you'll need an actual service object (i.e. `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`).  Something like this should work better:

```
$services |
    ForEach-Object {
        $service = Get-Service -Name $_

        $service.Stop()
        $service.WaitForStatus('Stopped')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , that is working now. Apologies I cut off the defined $service when pasting.